# RTMP or RTSP LIve Streaming URL Record in SD Card

Tags: java, record, rtsp, sd-card, rtmp

I want to record the RTMP or RTSP live Streaming URL in my SD card but I cant do it, I tried but I didn't get any solution regarding this issue so is there any way? please help, Thanks !

Comment: No one have any solution ? regrading this issue ?

Comment: What **exactly** of this can't you do? Is it connecting to a stream or maybe you don't know how to save access SD card? Which difficult part is not in the manual or any online tutorials? Anyways... I would expect the process to be (1) Connect to RTMP server using socket (2) After handshake process with server you receive the stream's bytes (3) Write incoming bytes to a byteArray (4) Save bytearray as file on disk....